# How to make a WPF content conditional on some bound data?

Tags: wpf, data-binding, mvvm, menuitem

I want to create a menu item but the displayed text depends on a property of the view model.
If the property `IsPlaying` is true, the MenuItem text should be "Pause", else it should be "Play".

Without this condition, the MenuItem should be something like:

```
<MenuItem Header="_Play" Command="{Binding Path=PlayCommand}" />
```

But, "Play" and "Pause" should interchange (and if possible PlayCommand should interchange with PauseCommand too, but this can be worked by having both the logic of PlayCommand and PauseCommand in PlayCommand)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest way to do this is first you should bind the `Header` to a `string Caption` property in your viewmodel which returns Play or Pause based on the value of `IsPlaying` and implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`. After this, just throw change notification for `Caption` also when `IsPlaying` is changed.

Although you can use a converter, but in this case it will be an overkill.

Comment: I first voted for the converter answer, but I think I'd go for this one in the end. It's a bit less "pretty", but seeing the relative simplicity of the issue here, this solution is probably the easiest and fastest one

Answer (score 1):

The best thing for this is a converter. Your code will look something like this:

```
<UserControl xmlns:myConverters="MyRandomNamespace">
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <myConverters:MyMenuTextConverter x:Key="MyMenuTextConverter" />
    </UserControl.Resources>

    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding IsPlaying, Converter={StaticResource MyMenuTextConverter }}" />
    </Grid>

</UserControl>
```

and in the converter:

```
namespace MyRandomNamespace 
{
    public class MyMenuTextConverter : IValueConverter 
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture) 
        {
            if ((bool) value == true)
               return "Pause";

            return "Play";
        }
    }
}
```

I've used a `TextBlock` to display the concept behind the binding, all you have to do is use the same binding syntax on the appropriate property of the MenuItem. I'm also returning literal text from the converter which is not optimal (personally i like my text converters to retrieve their values from a string resource file so that my app is culture aware), but you get the idea.

Comment: Another alternative to baking the strings into the converter (which is indeed 'not optimal' *grin*) is to define TrueText and FalseText properties on the converter, which can then be specified in the XAML converter resource.  This could be combined with a resource retrieval (TrueResourceKey and FalseResourceKey) to keep the converter code reusable without compromising localisation.

Answer (score 1):

A couple of ways to do this:

1. Use a Trigger.  Set a Trigger on IsPlaying = True, and set the Header and Command to Pause and PauseCommand respectively.
2. Have two menu items, Play and Pause, and use a pair of triggers to set their Visibility according to IsPlaying.  (You could also data-bind Visibility, but using triggers avoids the need to define a BooleanToInvisibilityConverter.)

Comment: +1 for option 1; They'd both work of course, as would the converter, but the Trigger is clean and simultaneously solves the Command problem.

Answer (score 1):

In WPF you can use a [DataTrigger](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.datatrigger.aspx) to change the content based on state in your viewmodel (you could even use this technique to swap out the template). Another alternative is to use the [VisualStateManager](http://timheuer.com/blog/archive/2008/06/04/silverlight-introduces-visual-state-manager-vsm.aspx) (the distant cousin of datatriggers created for Silverlight's absence thereof that was then backported to WPF as well) to do a similar change from one state (IsPlaying) to the next (!IsPlaying).

I would love to give a more detailed example but it's past my bedtime. Maybe later today.